Optionally invoke tag helpers in Razor page
This select will be populated normally:
<select ... asp-for=@Model.SelectedId asp-items=Model.Products>
</select>

Sometimes I want to render it as empty; I tried:
<select ... @if (!Model.IsEmpty) { <text>asp-for=@Model.SelectedId asp-items=Model.Products</text> }>
</select>

That doesn't work.
I could repeat that markup in an if-else block, but hope there's a cleaner way to optionally invoke those tag helpers?

If "empty" in this case specifically means that you don't want to use any asp-* binding at all, and not just that you want Model.Products to be an empty collection (which would make more sense to me, but I don't know your specific use case), then using two different markup instances is how I'd do it.

@David Yes the intention is to render an "empty" select (for use as a script template). I was hoping there's some tricky razor syntax that allows this use case, but alas. Thanks for confirming!

If you want to make dropdownlist optionally populate, change your code like below:
<select asp-for="SelectedId" asp-items="@(Model.IsEmpty?null:Model.Products)"></select>

Model design:
public class YourViewModel
{
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Products { get; set; }
    public bool IsEmpty { get; set; }
}


Works perfectly, thanks!
